# Why in my Angular application using typescript, is not changing my variable inside a function in this situation?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having a strange problem.

In my component CategoryComponent i have a variable in escope that is:

**@Input() category: CategoryModel;**

When i make a simple post with a service and return a data i change this variable to change so i make a function that do this:

```
if (category.uploading) {
  this.checkMedia(this.category, this.module);
}
```

Inside my function i make this:

```
checkMedia(model: any, module: String) {
    let counter = 0;
    var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
      const service =
        model instanceof CategoryModel
          ? this.categoryService
          : this.foodService;
      service
        .hasMedia(model)
        .pipe(
          switchMap((hasMedia) => {
            if (hasMedia) {
              return service.show(model, module);
            }
            return of(undefined);
          }),
          catchError((_) => {
            clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
            return of(undefined);
          })
        )
        .subscribe(
          (newModel) => {
            if (newModel) {
              if(newModel.hasMedia) {
                model.hasMedia = newModel.hasMedia;
                model.images = newModel.images;
                model.uploading = false;
                console.log(model);
                console.log(this.category);
                clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
                this.cd.detectChanges();
              }
            }
          },
          (_) => {
            clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
          }
        );
      counter++;
      if (counter == 3) {
        if (refreshIntervalId) {
          model.uploading = false;
          clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
          this.cd.detectChanges();
        }
      }
    }, 8000);
  }
```

Why in this part:

```
        model.hasMedia = newModel.hasMedia;
        model.images = newModel.images;
        model.uploading = false;
        console.log(model);
        console.log(this.category);
        clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
        this.cd.detectChanges();
```

My screen change only if i reference this variable directly like, **this.category.name = "TESTE";**, for example but when i use with the paremeter **model:any**, it's change the global variable when i see in console.log() but in my front page the state that i want is not changing why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THE MAIN CONCERN

The bit I don't understand, what are you doing with model? Why are you not using `this.model`? I would expect that you would be referencing model in your HTML somewhere and would thus need to update a class member variable `this.model = {blah-blah-blah}`. Have you declared a public property model somewhere in your class? Why is it not being updated? In your class you need to declare:

```
@Input() category: CategoryModel;
model: any;
```

And then in your code:

```
this.model = something
```

And then in your html:

```
{{ model | json }}
```

OTHER POTENTIAL ISSUES

What change detection strategy are you using? OnPush or default? You should not use OnPush unless you are confident with it. Its possible that because you are mutating model change detection is not kicking in. You should avoid object mutation. To fix this try adding this line:

```
model.hasMedia = newModel.hasMedia;
model.images = newModel.images;
model.uploading = false;
model = {...model}; // creates a new object reference which will cause Angular change detection to kick in
```

OR

```
import {cloneDeep} from 'lodash-es';

model.hasMedia = newModel.hasMedia;
model.images = newModel.images;
model.uploading = false;
model = cloneDeep(model); // creates a new object reference which will cause Angular change detection to kick in
```

I find the 2nd approach more readable. Let me know if it works. All the best.

This is mutation (BAD):

```
model.hasMedia = newModel.hasMedia;
model.images = newModel.images;
model.uploading = false;
```

This is not mutation (GOOD):

```
model = {
  ...model
  hasMedia: newModel.hasMedia;
  images: newModel.images;
  uploading: false;
}
```

EDIT ... USING RETURN VALUES

```
this.checkMedia(this.category, this.module).then((cat) => {
  this.category = cat;
});
```

and return a value from `checkMedia`

```
checkMedia(model: any, module: String): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    // your existing code
    resolve(model)
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you response, but is not working, i wanna change this model @Input() category: CategoryModel;, but i send this object inside a function that others model use, so i make a function called  this.checkMedia(this.category, this.module); that i pass this model in parameter. So if i pass in parameter i was thinking that if use model ( parameter ) is referecing this object, so i simple use model.hasMedia = newModel.hasMedia and it is supposed to work because if use this.category.hasMedia = newModel.hasMedia ( directly, it works )

Comment: OK does ... this.category = cloneDeep(model) ... work?

Comment: this.category.hasMedia = newModel.hasMedia; ( works ), but i wanna understand why it works and not by parameter

Comment: because i want to make a function that works for both objects and not creating something like checkCategoryMedia() and checkFoodMedia() you understand?

Comment: OK I think I understand, you are passing an object by reference and its not updating the object unless you assign to it directly - how about using return values instead? see edit to my answer

Comment: actually, im not overly impressed with my suggestion of returning a Promise, although it should work but its a bit complicated ... I see your solution is better if it only worked! Not sure why you are having this problem, passing by reference should work fine!

Comment: I guess a quick fix here is ... if (model instanceof CategoryModel) { this.category.hasMedia = newModel.hasMedia } else { this.food.hasMedia = newModel.hasMedia } ... but not an ideal solution!

Comment: you are very kind, thank you so much, i made some changes because of you response and i understand more about Typescript today, thanks :), i will update my answer!